# DLP for Phone calls

Tags: phone, voip, dlp

I would like to know if there is a DLP system that can monitor phone conversation, in order to search for sensitive data leakage by the company users to external users.

We know NSA does that :)
Is there a software/appliance that can handle such for a financial company against data leaks over phone calls?

Thanks,

Comment: Please note that as per the FAQ, product recommendations are not a suitable question for this website.

Comment: Go to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ to ask your question.

Comment: It would be worth rewording the question slightly so that this doesn't come across as a product recommendation. I'd be interested in the answer. I'm sure that there will be a class of products that will do this but it isn't by any means a trivial problem as it would require a system to reliably make sense of conversations. You are much better off getting people trained and regularly reminded of their security responsibilities + ensuring people only have access to data they really need.